# OPT value not passing through selenium due to "no such element"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to pass an OPT code using selenium, python but it does not work on this specific window; same with the "CONFIRM" button because It does not find the element. The ID's as shown on the screen shot is optValue and submitBtn. I tried :

`myVerificationCode = wd.find_element(By.ID, 'optValue')`

But the following does not find my element. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxBBw.png)

I want the element to be found by wd.find_element so I can pass my opt code value and click confirm next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to switch into the iframe (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)

Change "driver" variable for "wd" if thats your driver

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe")
    
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

and now you should be able to

```
myVerificationCode = wd.find_element(By.ID, 'optValue')
```